# How to input mass amounts of data into a mysql table in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`tag`, `realname`, `des`, `fifty_week_wl`, `fifty_week_wr`, `one_month_r`, `six_month_r`, `website`, `address`, `no_of_employees`, `ytdr`, `pe`, `eb_ebitda`, `ps`, `pb`, `div_yeild`, `gros_margin`, `operating_margin`, `return_on_equ`, `revenue`, `operating_income`, `income_tax_expense`, `net_income_adjusted`, `eps_adjusted`, `diluted_shares_outstanding`, `total_current_assets`, `cash_near_cash_items`, `short_term_investments`, `short_term_liabilities`, `long_term_borrowings`, `total_shareholders_equ`, `book_value_per_share`, `depreciation_amorization_cash`, `cash_from_operating_activites`, `capital_expenditures`, `dividends_paid`, `increase_in_capital_stocks`, `decrease_in_capital_stocks`, `free_cash_flow`, `free_cash_flow_per_share`, `yrevenue`, `yoperating_income`, `yincome_tax_expense`, `ynet_income_adjusted`, `yeps_adjusted`, `ydiluted_shares_outstanding`, `ytotal_current_assets`, `ycash_neaer_items`, `ytotal_shareholders_equ`, `ybook_value_per_share`, `ydepreciation_amorization_cash`, `ycash_from_operating_activites`, `ycapital_ependitures`, `ydividends_paid`, `yincrease_in_capital_stocks`, `yfree_cash_flow`, `yfree_cash_flow_per_share`, `yprice_earnings`, `yev_to_ebitda`, `yprice_to_sales`, `yprice_to_book`, `ydividyeild`, `common_shares_outstanding`, `market_capitalization`, `cash_and_equivalents`, `total_debt`, `shares_outstanding_m`, `floats`, `short_intrest_m`, `short_intrest_as_percent_of_float`, `days_to_cover_shorts`, `preferred_equity`, `minority_intrest`, `enterprise_value`, `price_target_date_graph`, `volume_close_spyclose_alpha_normalalpha_graph`, `other_owners`) VALUES ('RHT', 'RED HAT INC', 'Red Hat, Inc. develops and provides open source software and services, including the Red Hat Linux operating system. The Companys web site offers information and news about open source software and provides an online community of open source software users and developers.', '88.75', '99.2%', '8.6%', '35.9%', 'www.redhat.com', '1801 Varsity Drive Raleigh, NC 27606 United States', '11,870', '45.7%', '2/15,71.6x,2/16,60.2x,2/17,60.8x,2/18,70.2x,2/19E,51.4x,2/20E,43.6x,2/21E,37.2x', '2/15,35.5x,2/16,29.0x,2/17,31.8x,2/18,42.8x,2/19E,32.5x,2/20E,27.5x,2/21E,24.7x', '2/15,7.2x,2/16,5.8x,2/17,6.2x,2/18,8.9x,2/19E,9.1x,2/20E,7.9x,2/21E,7.1x', '2/15,9.8x,2/16,8.9x,2/17,11.7x,2/18,17.8x,2/19E,16.2x,2/20E,12.9x,2/21E,8.3x', '2/15,0.0%,2/16,0.0%,2/17,0.0%,2/18,0.0%,2/19E,0.0%,2/20E,0.0%,2/21E,0.0%', '2/15,84.7,2/16,84.9,2/17,85.3,2/18,85.2,2/19E,86.6,2/20E,86.8,2/21E,86.8', '2/15,14.0,2/16,14.0,2/17,13.8,2/18,16.2,2/19E,24.0,2/20E,24.5,2/21E,25.3', '2/15,12.7,2/16,15.2,2/17,19.7,2/18,19.0,2/19E,34.8,2/20E,33.7,2/21E,26.8', '8/15,504,11/15,524,11/15,544,2/16,568,5/16,600,8/16,629,2/17,677,5/17,723,8/17,748,11/17,772,2/18,808,5/18E,855,8/18E,882,11/18E', '8/15,76,11/15,69,11/15,72,2/16,75,5/16,82,8/16,94,2/17,88,5/17,135,8/17,118,11/17,132,2/18,165,5/18E,214,8/18E,216,11/18E', '8/15,21,11/15,19,11/15,16,2/16,11,5/16,21,8/16,26,2/17,12,5/17,35,8/17,15,11/17,155,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,58,11/15,49,11/15,53,2/16,61,5/16,60,8/16,65,2/17,74,5/17,99,8/17,102,11/17,113,2/18,127,5/18E,163,8/18E,166,11/18E', '8/15,0.32,11/15,0.26,11/15,0.29,2/16,0.33,5/16,0.33,8/16,0.36,2/17,0.41,5/17,0.54,8/17,0.55,11/17,0.64,2/18,0.69,5/18E,0.89,8/18E,0.89,11/18E', '8/15,187,11/15,186,11/15,185,2/16,184,5/16,183,8/16,181,2/17,182,5/17,183,8/17,186,11/17,177,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,1,706,11/15,1,774,11/15,1,872,2/16,1,884,5/16,1,848,8/16,2,316,2/17,2,302,5/17,2,332,8/17,2,505,11/17,3,135,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,992,11/15,942,11/15,928,2/16,1,032,5/16,971,8/16,1,091,2/17,1,230,5/17,1,210,8/17,1,331,11/17,1,724,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,181,11/15,194,11/15,281,2/16,365,5/16,365,8/16,370,2/17,408,5/17,449,8/17,385,11/17,318,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,1,262,11/15,1,312,11/15,1,496,2/16,1,504,5/16,1,509,8/16,1,815,2/17,1,791,5/17,1,796,8/17,1,825,11/17,2,225,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,725,11/15,729,11/15,724,2/16,729,5/16,735,8/16,746,2/17,751,5/17,757,8/17,762,11/17,744,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,1,368,11/15,1,345,11/15,1,334,2/16,1,349,5/16,1,318,8/16,1,247,2/17,1,306,5/17,1,400,8/17,1,433,11/17,1,470,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,$7.48,11/15,$7.36,11/15,$7.36,2/16,$7.45,5/16,$7.34,8/16,$7.05,2/17,$7.35,5/17,$7.91,8/17,$8.10,11/17,$8.30,2/18,$8.34,5/18E,$9.23,8/18E,$9.99,11/18E', '8/15,19,11/15,20,11/15,19,2/16,21,5/16,21,8/16,22,2/17,22,5/17,24,8/17,26,11/17,26,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,123,11/15,148,11/15,250,2/16,232,5/16,97,8/16,318,2/17,258,5/17,143,8/17,160,11/17,362,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,(10),11/15,(8),11/15,(12),2/16,(18),5/16,(16),8/16,(19),2/17,(26),5/17,(26),8/17,(17),11/17,(17),2/18,(17),5/18E,(17),8/18E,(18),11/18E', '8/15,0,11/15,0,11/15,0,2/16,0,5/16,0,8/16,0,2/17,0,5/17,0,8/17,0,11/17,0,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,0,11/15,1,11/15,0,2/16,1,5/16,1,8/16,1,2/17,3,5/17,1,8/17,1,11/17,0,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,(70),11/15,(78),11/15,(114),2/16,(66),5/16,(127),8/16,(139),2/17,(62),5/17,(75),8/17,(100),11/17,0,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,113,11/15,140,11/15,238,2/16,215,5/16,81,8/16,300,2/17,232,5/17,117,8/17,144,11/17,345,2/18,250,5/18E,116,8/18E,175,11/18E', '8/15,0.62,11/15,0.76,11/15,1.30,2/16,1.18,5/16,0.45,8/16,1.68,2/17,1.31,5/17,0.66,8/17,0.81,11/17,1.95,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,504,11/15,524,11/15,544,2/16,568,5/16,600,8/16,629,2/17,677,5/17,723,8/17,748,11/17,772,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,76,11/15,69,11/15,72,2/16,75,5/16,82,8/16,94,2/17,88,5/17,135,8/17,118,11/17,132,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,21,11/15,19,11/15,16,2/16,11,5/16,21,8/16,26,2/17,12,5/17,35,8/17,15,11/17,155,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,58,11/15,49,11/15,53,2/16,61,5/16,60,8/16,65,2/17,74,5/17,99,8/17,102,11/17,113,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,0.32,11/15,0.26,11/15,0.29,2/16,0.33,5/16,0.33,8/16,0.36,2/17,0.41,5/17,0.54,8/17,0.55,11/17,0.64,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,187,11/15,186,11/15,185,2/16,184,5/16,183,8/16,181,2/17,182,5/17,183,8/17,186,11/17,177,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,1,706,11/15,1,774,11/15,1,872,2/16,1,884,5/16,1,848,8/16,2,316,2/17,2,302,5/17,2,332,8/17,2,505,11/17,3,135,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,992,11/15,942,11/15,928,2/16,1,032,5/16,971,8/16,1,091,2/17,1,230,5/17,1,210,8/17,1,331,11/17,1,724,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,,11/15,,11/15,,2/16,,5/16,,8/16,,2/17,,5/17,,8/17,,11/17,,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,$7.48,11/15,$7.36,11/15,$7.36,2/16,$7.45,5/16,$7.34,8/16,$7.05,2/17,$7.35,5/17,$7.91,8/17,$8.10,11/17,$8.30,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,19,11/15,20,11/15,19,2/16,21,5/16,21,8/16,22,2/17,22,5/17,24,8/17,26,11/17,26,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,123,11/15,148,11/15,250,2/16,232,5/16,97,8/16,318,2/17,258,5/17,143,8/17,160,11/17,362,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,(10),11/15,(8),11/15,(12),2/16,(18),5/16,(16),8/16,(19),2/17,(26),5/17,(26),8/17,(17),11/17,(17),2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,0,11/15,0,11/15,0,2/16,0,5/16,0,8/16,0,2/17,0,5/17,0,8/17,0,11/17,0,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,0,11/15,1,11/15,0,2/16,1,5/16,1,8/16,1,2/17,3,5/17,1,8/17,1,11/17,0,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,113,11/15,140,11/15,238,2/16,215,5/16,81,8/16,300,2/17,232,5/17,117,8/17,144,11/17,345,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,0.62,11/15,0.76,11/15,1.30,2/16,1.18,5/16,0.45,8/16,1.68,2/17,1.31,5/17,0.66,8/17,0.81,11/17,1.95,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '8/15,67.91,11/15,76.47,11/15,59.69,2/16,66.63,5/16,60.29,8/16,61.25,2/17,62.78,5/17,65.52,8/17,68.60,11/17,69.19,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,33.41,11/15,38.13,11/15,29.03,2/16,34.09,5/16,31.15,8/16,31.76,2/17,33.29,5/17,35.89,8/17,39.55,11/17,42.83,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,6.96,11/15,7.56,11/15,5.82,2/16,6.60,5/16,5.93,8/16,6.17,2/17,6.35,5/17,7.23,8/17,8.09,11/17,8.94,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,9.65,11/15,11.06,11/15,8.87,2/16,10.40,5/16,9.94,8/16,11.74,2/17,12.18,5/17,13.58,8/17,15.66,11/17,17.75,2/18,#N/AInvalidField,5/18E,#N/AInvalidField,8/18E,#N/AInvalidField,11/18E', '8/15,0.00,11/15,0.00,11/15,0.00,2/16,0.00,5/16,0.00,8/16,0.00,2/17,0.00,5/17,0.00,8/17,0.00,11/17,0.00,2/18,,5/18E,,8/18E,,11/18E', '177.07', '31,288.21', '2,472.93', '768.00', '177.1', '99.4%', '5.7', '3.26%', '3.37', '0.00', '0.00', '29,583.28', '6/18/2018,176.10,172.21,6/15/2018,174.99,171.86,6/14/2018,175.90,171.50,6/13/2018,174.03,170.43,6/12/2018,173.01,170.76,6/11/2018,170.23,170.76,6/8/2018,171.06,170.76,6/7/2018,169.13,170.76,6/6/2018,172.49,170.76,6/5/2018,172.33,170.76,6/4/2018,169.45,170.76,6/1/2018,167.90,170.76,5/31/2018,162.42,170.76,5/30/2018,164.38,170.76,5/29/2018,162.93,170.76,5/28/2018,165.10,170.76,5/25/2018,165.10,170.76,5/24/2018,165.09,170.76,5/23/2018,164.26,170.76,5/22/2018,161.41,170.76,5/21/2018,162.99,170.76,5/18/2018,163.28,170.76,5/17/2018,161.08,170.76,5/16/2018,161.96,170.76,5/15/2018,163.56,170.76,5/14/2018,164.75,170.76,5/11/2018,172.47,169.90,5/10/2018,171.48,169.90,5/9/2018,171.16,169.90,5/8/2018,168.60,168.52,5/7/2018,168.76,168.52,5/4/2018,166.10,168.52,5/3/2018,164.13,168.52,5/2/2018,162.60,168.52,5/1/2018,163.14,168.52,4/30/2018,163.06,168.52,4/27/2018,163.31,168.52,4/26/2018,163.11,168.52,4/25/2018,158.14,168.52,4/24/2018,160.10,168.52,4/23/2018,160.63,168.52,4/20/2018,159.28,168.52,4/19/2018,160.14,168.52,4/18/2018,161.67,168.52,4/17/2018,162.23,168.52,4/16/2018,160.53,168.00,4/13/2018,157.71,168.00,4/12/2018,159.20,168.00,4/11/2018,156.40,168.00,4/10/2018,156.75,167.75,4/9/2018,151.33,167.75,4/6/2018,149.17,167.75,4/5/2018,151.07,167.75,4/4/2018,151.82,167.75,4/3/2018,147.26,167.75,4/2/2018,144.82,167.75,3/30/2018,149.51,166.82,3/29/2018,149.51,166.82,3/28/2018,146.20,166.82,3/27/2018,154.42,166.82,3/26/2018,153.09,155.74,3/23/2018,147.90,146.00,3/22/2018,151.03,146.00,3/21/2018,154.55,140.85,3/20/2018,155.28,137.85,3/19/2018,152.11,138.14,3/16/2018,154.17,137.45,3/15/2018,154.43,137.45,3/14/2018,155.04,137.45,3/13/2018,153.95,137.45,3/12/2018,155.08,137.45,3/9/2018,155.48,136.76,3/8/2018,153.46,136.76,3/7/2018,153.31,136.76,3/6/2018,149.72,136.76,3/5/2018,149.83,136.21,3/2/2018,148.76,136.21,3/1/2018,145.44,136.21,2/28/2018,147.40,136.21,2/27/2018,147.44,136.21,2/26/2018,148.03,136.21,2/23/2018,146.62,136.21,2/22/2018,144.66,136.21,2/21/2018,143.42,136.21,2/20/2018,144.32,136.21,2/19/2018,142.71,136.21,2/16/2018,142.71,136.21,2/15/2018,140.07,136.21,2/14/2018,134.19,136.21,2/13/2018,132.03,136.21,2/12/2018,129.32,136.21,2/9/2018,126.84,136.21,2/8/2018,124.65,136.21,2/7/2018,128.81,136.21,2/6/2018,128.68,136.21,2/5/2018,127.05,136.21,2/2/2018,128.01,136.21,2/1/2018,130.62,136.21,1/31/2018,131.38,136.21,1/30/2018,131.46,136.21,1/29/2018,132.95,136.21,1/26/2018,135.22,136.21,1/25/2018,130.90,137.04,1/24/2018,128.89,137.04,1/23/2018,128.15,137.04,1/22/2018,128.01,136.48,1/19/2018,125.94,136.48,1/18/2018,125.47,136.48,1/17/2018,126.60,136.48,1/16/2018,124.59,136.48,1/15/2018,125.95,136.48,1/12/2018,125.95,136.48,1/11/2018,126.16,136.48,1/10/2018,124.51,136.48,1/9/2018,124.15,136.48,1/8/2018,125.21,136.48,1/5/2018,124.14,136.48,1/4/2018,123.98,136.48,1/3/2018,123.06,136.48,1/2/2018,121.04,136.96,1/1/2018,120.10,136.96,12/29/2017,120.10,136.96,12/28/2017,121.13,136.96,12/27/2017,121.22,136.96,12/26/2017,120.61,136.96,12/25/2017,122.92,136.96,12/22/2017,122.92,136.96,12/21/2017,123.13,136.96,12/20/2017,122.00,136.96,12/19/2017,128.86,130.43,12/18/2017,129.44,127.26,12/15/2017,128.78,127.08,12/14/2017,126.13,125.69,12/13/2017,126.49,125.50,12/12/2017,125.75,123.11,12/11/2017,126.62,122.54,12/8/2017,125.29,121.92,12/7/2017,123.80,121.46,12/6/2017,121.94,121.46,12/5/2017,120.87,121.46,12/4/2017,120.31,121.46,12/1/2017,125.26,121.08,11/30/2017,126.76,121.08,11/29/2017,124.49,121.08,11/28/2017,129.24,121.08,11/27/2017,128.20,121.08,11/24/2017,128.36,121.08,11/23/2017,126.59,121.08,11/22/2017,126.59,121.08,11/21/2017,128.51,121.08,11/20/2017,127.00,121.08,11/17/2017,125.95,121.08,11/16/2017,126.63,121.08,11/15/2017,123.82,121.08,11/14/2017,124.49,121.08,11/13/2017,123.99,121.08,11/10/2017,124.18,121.08,11/9/2017,123.50,121.08,11/8/2017,123.92,121.08,11/7/2017,121.92,121.08,11/6/2017,121.08,121.08,11/3/2017,121.64,121.08,11/2/2017,120.99,121.08,11/1/2017,121.26,121.08,10/31/2017,120.83,121.08,10/30/2017,121.10,121.08,10/27/2017,120.77,121.08,10/26/2017,120.29,121.08,10/25/2017,120.22,121.08,10/24/2017,121.28,121.08,10/23/2017,122.13,121.08,10/20/2017,121.80,121.08,10/19/2017,121.60,121.08,10/18/2017,120.69,121.08,10/17/2017,121.12,121.08,10/16/2017,120.89,121.08,10/13/2017,121.10,121.08,10/12/2017,120.91,121.08,10/11/2017,119.37,121.08,10/10/2017,118.35,121.08,10/9/2017,117.07,121.08,10/6/2017,117.06,121.08,10/5/2017,115.52,121.08,10/4/2017,112.74,121.08,10/3/2017,111.93,121.08,10/2/2017,112.18,121.08,9/29/2017,110.86,120.69,9/28/2017,109.59,120.69,9/27/2017,109.92,120.59,9/26/2017,110.07,120.59,9/25/2017,105.76,116.81,9/22/2017,106.30,115.22,9/21/2017,106.84,110.85,9/20/2017,106.99,110.46,9/19/2017,107.14,109.39,9/18/2017,107.44,109.39,9/15/2017,107.30,108.61,9/14/2017,107.74,108.61,9/13/2017,107.83,108.61,9/12/2017,107.66,108.04,9/11/2017,107.62,107.67,9/8/2017,107.12,107.67,9/7/2017,107.04,107.67,9/6/2017,106.34,107.15,9/5/2017,106.81,107.15,9/4/2017,107.46,107.00,9/1/2017,107.46,107.00,8/31/2017,107.50,107.00,8/30/2017,106.16,107.00,8/29/2017,105.52,107.00,8/28/2017,105.59,107.00,8/25/2017,105.33,107.00,8/24/2017,104.65,107.31,8/23/2017,104.00,107.31,8/22/2017,104.89,107.31,8/21/2017,102.65,107.31,8/18/2017,100.43,107.04,8/17/2017,100.66,107.04,8/16/2017,101.75,107.04,8/15/2017,99.99,107.04,8/14/2017,99.74,107.04,8/11/2017,98.34,107.04,8/10/2017,95.95,107.04,8/9/2017,97.70,107.04,8/8/2017,98.07,107.04,8/7/2017,98.88,107.04,8/4/2017,98.36,107.04,8/3/2017,98.19,107.04,8/2/2017,98.35,107.04,8/1/2017,100.02,107.04,7/31/2017,98.87,107.04,7/28/2017,98.51,107.04,7/27/2017,98.92,107.04,7/26/2017,100.67,107.04,7/25/2017,99.92,107.04,7/24/2017,99.45,107.04,7/21/2017,98.94,107.04,7/20/2017,98.92,107.04,7/19/2017,99.25,107.04,7/18/2017,98.61,107.04,7/17/2017,98.53,107.04,7/14/2017,98.42,107.04,7/13/2017,97.77,107.04,7/12/2017,98.84,107.04,7/11/2017,97.41,107.04,7/10/2017,97.25,107.04,7/7/2017,96.55,107.04,7/6/2017,94.91,107.04,7/5/2017,95.54,107.04,7/4/2017,94.79,107.04,7/3/2017,94.79,107.04,6/30/2017,95.75,107.04,6/29/2017,95.51,107.04,6/28/2017,96.81,107.04,6/27/2017,96.00,107.04,6/26/2017,98.19,107.04,6/23/2017,99.42,107.04,6/22/2017,98.88,107.31,6/21/2017,98.58,107.31,6/20/2017,89.96,99.35,6/19/2017,90.35,95.10,6/16/2017,87.85,95.10,6/15/2017,87.92,95.10,6/14/2017,88.92,95.10,6/13/2017,89.28,95.10,6/12/2017,88.72,95.10,6/9/2017,88.85,95.10,6/8/2017,91.95,95.10,6/7/2017,91.93,95.10,6/6/2017,91.66,95.10,6/5/2017,91.75,95.10,6/2/2017,91.54,95.10,6/1/2017,90.72,95.10,5/31/2017,89.57,95.10,5/30/2017,89.42,95.10,5/29/2017,88.58,94.90,5/26/2017,88.58,94.90,5/25/2017,88.77,94.90,5/24/2017,87.99,94.60,5/23/2017,87.63,94.60,5/22/2017,87.90,94.29,5/19/2017,86.18,94.29,5/18/2017,85.52,94.29,5/17/2017,85.60,94.29,5/16/2017,89.64,94.29,5/15/2017,89.66,94.29,5/12/2017,88.25,94.29,5/11/2017,88.55,94.29,5/10/2017,89.14,94.29,5/9/2017,88.58,94.29,5/8/2017,88.20,94.21,5/5/2017,88.61,94.21,5/4/2017,87.89,94.21,5/3/2017,87.23,94.21,5/2/2017,88.18,94.00,5/1/2017,88.29,94.00,4/28/2017,88.08,94.00,4/27/2017,88.15,94.00,4/26/2017,87.71,94.00,4/25/2017,87.59,94.00,4/24/2017,87.44,94.00,4/21/2017,87.02,94.00,4/20/2017,87.42,94.00,4/19/2017,87.27,94.00,4/18/2017,86.74,94.00,4/17/2017,86.17,94.00,4/14/2017,85.93,94.00,4/13/2017,85.93,94.00,4/12/2017,85.43,94.00,4/11/2017,85.16,94.00,4/10/2017,85.04,94.00,4/7/2017,84.91,94.00,4/6/2017,85.00,94.00,4/5/2017,84.68,94.00,4/4/2017,85.61,94.00,4/3/2017,86.48,94.00,3/31/2017,86.50,94.00,3/30/2017,85.92,94.00,3/29/2017,86.73,94.00,3/28/2017,86.48,94.00,3/27/2017,82.20,90.48,3/24/2017,82.96,90.00,3/23/2017,82.76,89.00,3/22/2017,82.55,87.12,3/21/2017,81.31,87.27,3/20/2017,84.51,87.04,3/17/2017,83.65,86.50,3/16/2017,84.10,86.50,3/15/2017,83.27,86.50,3/14/2017,82.58,86.50,3/13/2017,82.88,86.50,3/10/2017,82.21,86.50,3/9/2017,81.56,86.50,3/8/2017,82.05,86.19,3/7/2017,81.97,86.19,3/6/2017,82.03,86.19,3/3/2017,82.05,86.19,3/2/2017,82.43,86.19,3/1/2017,83.24,86.19,2/28/2017,82.81,86.19,2/27/2017,83.78,86.30,2/24/2017,84.86,86.30,2/23/2017,84.60,86.30,2/22/2017,84.71,86.30,2/21/2017,83.75,86.30,2/20/2017,82.60,86.30,2/17/2017,82.60,86.30,2/16/2017,81.53,86.30,2/15/2017,81.05,86.30,2/14/2017,80.09,86.30,2/13/2017,79.77,86.30,2/10/2017,79.25,86.30,2/9/2017,79.31,86.30,2/8/2017,78.66,86.30,2/7/2017,78.86,86.30,2/6/2017,78.22,86.30,2/3/2017,78.13,86.30,2/2/2017,77.71,86.30,2/1/2017,76.07,86.30,1/31/2017,75.88,86.15,1/30/2017,75.51,86.15,1/27/2017,75.70,86.15,1/26/2017,75.25,86.15,1/25/2017,76.43,86.15,1/24/2017,75.43,86.15,1/23/2017,74.06,86.15,1/20/2017,74.20,86.15,1/19/2017,73.92,86.15,1/18/2017,73.60,86.15,1/17/2017,72.77,86.15,1/16/2017,73.36,86.15,1/13/2017,73.36,86.15,1/12/2017,73.03,86.15,1/11/2017,72.33,86.00,1/10/2017,71.66,86.00,1/9/2017,72.14,86.00,1/6/2017,73.80,86.00,1/5/2017,73.10,86.04,1/4/2017,73.10,86.04,1/3/2017,70.12,86.04,1/2/2017,69.70,86.04,12/30/2016,69.70,86.04,12/29/2016,69.65,86.04,12/28/2016,70.02,86.04,12/27/2016,70.19,86.04,12/26/2016,71.01,86.04,12/23/2016,71.01,86.04,12/22/2016,68.71,86.18,12/21/2016,79.79,88.96,12/20/2016,79.39,90.32,12/19/2016,80.47,90.30', '', '#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,VANGUARDGROUP,18,766,017,257,553,FMRLLC,16,910,690,3,563,211,BLACKROCK,11,741,665,260,050,JENNISONASSOCIATES,8,732,657,-819,415,STATESTREETCORP,6,508,959,-275,404,CLEARBRIDGE,4,749,431,-245,791,UBS,4,459,755,39,116,NORTHERNTRUSTCORPO,3,528,122,-66,658,HARBORCAPITALADVIS,3,395,135,742,480,WILLIAMBLAIR,2,548,155,-459,887,ARROWSTREETCAPLIMI,2,235,150,90,550,THRIVENTFINANCIALF,2,112,983,-83,943,GEODECAPITALMANAGE,1,991,747,67,433,JPMORGANCHASE&CO,1,899,422,-110,614,NORGESBANK,1,850,571,197,902,TIAA-CREF,1,800,802,-290,218,SUSTAINABLEGROWTHA,1,773,958,-604,976,FREDALGERMANAGEMEN,1,732,589,865,244,VOYAINVESTMENTMANA,1,690,758,1,029,028');
//Inserts data into a mysql table with a structure of :
```

Image of structure

[image]

Image of structure continued

[image]

Final image of structure

[image]

```
#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

Comment: Don't store CSVs in columns. You probably shouldn't be using latin1.

Comment: looks like a job for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: What should I use instead of latin 1?

Comment: Probably UTF8, unless there is no chance of non-ascii characters coming to your DB.

Comment: user3783243, I tried changing the collation to UTF8 and I got the same error! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this with PHP, [PDO prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) is probably your best bet, with named inputs to improve code readability.

If you can load directly from a file without involving PHP, then have MySQL do it directly (`LOAD DATA INFILE`).